# how to enable showing tag categories in openapi 3 swagger ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I use springdoc openapi version 1.5.7. left list of tags not showing. how can I enable it?
[image]

Comment: I guess that you may need to set springdoc.swagger-ui.filter to "true". My guess is based on the documentation here: https://springdoc.org

Comment: it did not work @Juvanis

Comment: Your question is vague. Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and if possible, share a minimum reproducible example. From the image that you're shared currently, I don't know how you got the categories thing on the left as it's not part of the official Swagger UI.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve something similar using the Quarkus-based rest application? I tried to achieve something similar for my quarkus-based application but could not get anything. Please find my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74627820/7584240